# Query Support (ROQL tabular queries, Query parameters, ROQL tabular queries) not work in oraacle rightnow REST API

Tags: android, ios, oracle, rightnow-crm, roql

I am working on mobile application which is integrate with Oracle RightNow. I am refere latest document of rightnow REST API.

[Document of rightnow REST API](http://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/devdocs/august2015/Connect_REST_API/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Connect_REST_API.1.18.html)

It is work fine in normal request using REST API.  But when I am using Query Support. It is not working.

As per doc, below url is work, but not working in my case.

**For Query parameters**

https://username:password@mysite.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.3/accounts/7?fields=id,lookupName,accountHierarchy.links

**For ROQL object queries**

https://username:password@mysite.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.3/accounts/?q=id>10

**For ROQL tabular queries**

https://username:password@mysite.custhelp.com/services/rest/connect/v1.3/queryResults/?query=select id from accounts;

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 15.5?  ROQL support in the REST API was just released in 15.8.

Comment: Oracle Service Cloud May 2015 SP2 (Build 116 - 09/21/2015 22:54)
 CE Version: allsites-rnw-release-15-5-0-1-sp2 PL: 
Client Time Zone Data Version: 2015a-1.el6 (32/64 bit)..

Comment: May 15 is 15.5 (year.month).  You're looking at the 15.8 docs, which describe ROQL.  You'll need to have the site upgraded to 15.8 before you can perform the type of queries that you're trying.

Comment: Were you able to review the documentation to confirm?  Your OSvC version is the reason that you're unable to perform the query that you're attempting.  This should be marked as the solution.